# FLV Metadata Editor GUI

Tags: command-line, video, gui, metadata, flv

Are there any programs for Ubuntu 13.04 that allow the user to edit the metadata of FLV videos? I would prefer a graphical user interface. Command-lines are fine if that is all that exists.

Comment: I do not want a video editor. I need a metadata editor for videos, specifically FLV videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[flvmeta](http://www.flvmeta.com/) is a command line tool available for Windows, Mac and Linux that can *add* metadata (in the form of a string) to flv files

Basic usage:

```
flvmeta --add=NAME=VALUE inputfile.flv outputfile.flv
```

(replace NAME and VALUE with your values)

You can check whether the metadata has been added by running

```
flvmeta -m outputfile.flv
```

Please note that flvmeta 1.1.0 at least is needed for this to work, while the version packaged for Ubuntu 13.04 is an old release, v1.0.11.

Comment: collier@Laptop:~/tasks/youtube$ flvmeta --add=Artist=Devyn ./test.flv ./test2.flv
Error: cannot open --add=Artist=Devyn for reading.
collier@Laptop:~/tasks/youtube$ flvmeta --add=Artist=Devyn ./test.flv
Error: cannot open --add=Artist=Devyn for reading.
collier@Laptop:~/tasks/youtube$ flvmeta -U --add Artist=Devyn ./test.flv
Error: cannot open -U for reading.
collier@Laptop:~/tasks/youtube$ flvmeta ./test.flv -U --add=Artist=Devyn
collier@Laptop:~/tasks/youtube$ flvmeta -m ./test2.flv
Error: cannot open -m for reading.

Comment: If I check the metadata through my file manager (Nautilus), the added metadata does not appear.

Comment: Try those same commands without the preceding "./" . I've got it working on Ubuntu 12.04. If your problems are actual bugs then you'll have to submit a bug report

Comment: Clearly, something is wrong on my system if other are successfully using flvmeta. As a result, I will mark hellocatfood's answer as the best.

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't help you get a completely functional version. I'll be upgrading my Ubuntu soon so can check if it still works

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson As the author of FLVmeta, I have to step in to clarify a few things. First of all, the answer uses flvmeta 1.1.x, which is the branch in which metadata injection was implemented, while your error messages indicate you are using the old version 1.0.x, which unfortunately is the one currently packaged until 13.04. Also, I think the comment "very unstable and does not work" is kind of misleading considering the issue here was only a version mismatch.

Comment: @SirDarius   I have Ubuntu 13.04. All of my applications are up-to-date. What is the best link to the newest version of FLVmeta? Is there a PPA that I can add to my system? I will delete the comment above. Where is the best documentation for FLVmeta?

Comment: It can be downloaded from http://www.flvmeta.com/, and the online manual is located at http://flvmeta.com/flvmeta.1.html. I know the latest version has been packaged for Saucy: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flvmeta/1.1.1-1

Answer (score 1):

[**PiTiVi**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pitivi) [image: Install pitivi] - allows users to easily edit audio/video projects based on the GStreamer framework. PiTIVi provides several ways of creating and modifying a timeline. Ranging from a simple synopsis view (a-la iMovie) to the full-blown editing view (aka Complex View) which puts you in complete control of your editing.

For install it from a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), use next command:

```
sudo apt-get install pitivi
```

PiTiVi homepage: http://www.pitivi.org/

Comment: This seems like a canned response that doesn't actually address the original posters' needs. They want an FLV metadata editor, not a video editor

Comment: hellocatfood is correct, I want to edit the metadata.

Comment: I have some FLV files that I want to put on the interent, but I want to add metadata like the author, film data, etc.

Comment: Ok, you can do this with PiTiVi.

Comment: How can you do this with PiTiVi?

Comment: @hellocatfood [PiTiVi Video Editor Manual](http://pitivi.org/manual/index.html) - you will find everything there, including how to insert files, edit metadata etc.

Comment: Using Pitivi to edit metadata only allows me to set the author field. Plus, this process requires me to recreate the FLV by clicking "Render".

Comment: Source: http://packages.debian.org/unstable/gnome/pitivi